# how to do a db query in codeigniter which catches dependence data

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I'm trying to create a database statement in codeigniter, but I'm not sure how or if what I want to do is possible.

I want to ask the db in a way like this

```
SELECT ID FROM DB WHERE ARG1 = VAL1 

$this->db->where('ARG1', $VAL1)
```

and check if there are other entries that have `ID` as `VAL1` and return them too

Is it possible, and how I have to do it in codeigniter?

The datas are a kind of `"parent"->"child"->"parent"->"child"...`

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. ```$this->db->where('ARG1', $VAL1);
$this->db->or_where('ID', $VAL1); ``` // Would produce: WHERE ARG1 = 'VAL1' OR ID = 'VAL1